# SharePoint 2013 Remote Event Recievers - How Reliable?

Tags: office, remote-event-receiver, sharepoint-online

It is business critical for us that Remote Event Receivers DO fire, however Microsoft do not guarantee they will (Confirmed to us by Microsoft after raising this issue on a support ticket).

What we need is a workaround, has anyone found another way to execute code on change/new events in SharePoint 2013

Answer (score 4):

You will not be able to capture events on SharePoint in a reliable way for mission critical events. The best you can hope for is to poll the data at intervals for the changes you are looking for.

SharePoint was not designed for these types of systems, and does not support them well. If you implement workarounds those workarounds are going to cause you endless grief. I suggest you re-think your architecture and consider a real database with transaction support.

Comment: Very valid point, we have experience with timer jobs and this is possibly the way to go, yet not quite good enough when we need up to date info quickly, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The way we handle it in O365 is kind of a hack and similar to a Timer Job, but it works.

We make a C# console application and host it as a web job in Azure, and have the job run every 5 minutes or so.  When the job runs, it checks every item in the list that doesn't have "Completed" in a metadata field that we specify, and runs the job for each one of those items, then changed the field to "Completed".

You will have to create an app for the web job so it can access SharePoint, but if you're doing remote event receivers and timer jobs, you probably know how to do that.

So it's not quite what you're looking for, but it works well enough.  It's the closest solution I've found to do this type of thing in O365.

If you're not in O365 and you're on-premise, you can just use a Timer Job, a regular event receiver, or a Visual Studio workflow.

Comment: Similar to the first answer, appreciate the comment :)

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Webhooks, for the people still interested

[SharePoint Webhooks Overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/webhooks/overview-sharepoint-webhooks)

Comment: @P Clegg but one drawback is that Webhooks do not support synchronous events such as adding, editing, deleting..  this is a major drawbacks, when we did a migration between on-presmies to office 365, we use to have many synchronous server-side ER, and to migrate them SP online does not support any operation rather than using remote ER..

Comment: @johnG, good point, we personally never needed "ing" events just the "ed"s, so this is an answer for us, just be aware that the web hooks expire every six months and have to be re-added.

Comment: @P Clegg yes i know so that why in our case there were not any approach we can follow rather than using RER..